# Do I need Plugins for ActiveMQ?

Tags: grails, activemq-classic

as a newbie regarding ActiveMQ, I just tried to connect from Grails to a queue. I took a look at the JMS plugin, the ActiveMQ plugin and "the Definitive Guide to Grails" book.

THe book shows me that I just need to drop some jars, wire some beans and that's it:

```
jmsFactory(org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory) { bean ->
    bean.destroyMethod = "stop"
    connectionFactory = { org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
        brokerURL = "tcp://localhost:61616"
    }
}
jmsTemplate(org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate) {
    connectionFactory = jmsFactory
}
jmsMessageListener(org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter, ref("messageService")) {
    defaultListenerMethod = "onMessage"
}
jmsContainer(org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer) {
    connectionFactory = jmsFactory
    destinationName = "demoQueue"
    messageListener = jmsMessageListener
    transactionManager = ref("transactionManager")
    autoStartup = false
}
```

I tested it and it seems to work like a charm. Even transactions work.

So is there a need for me to use one of the plugins? Do I miss something?

Comment: did you try persisting the message with mysql or any other db via jdbc? I am having problem in persisting messages. It would be great if you can share your resource.groovy file and that how did you added persistence

Comment: the queue manager ensures that messages are delivered. So nothing to do there regarding persistence. Within the Grails app, messages are just received and then you can persist them through normal domain classes. But as I remember, you are in a transactional context. Maybe that your problem. Why not post a new question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not a need to use the plugin if you are willing to integrate it yourself.

I use the jms plugin and manually configure ActiveMQ.

You can automate inclusion of the JMS plugin and the ActiveMQ jar in **BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
repositories {
    ...
    mavenCentral()
    ...
}
plugins {
    ...
    runtime ":jms:1.2"
    ...
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.5.1"
    ...
}
```

And configure an ActiveMQ embedded broker in **spring/resources.groovy**:

```
beans = {
    ...
    jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
        targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
            brokerURL = "vm://localhost"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

> I guess I don't need the embedded broker since I use an external one.

To use an external broker simply change the brokerURL defined in **spring/resources.groovy**.

---

> What about the JMS-Plugin. Which benefits do I have from using it?

The JMS plugin provides useful Grails integration.  See the [Grails JMS Plugin 1.2 Reference](http://gpc.github.com/grails-jms/docs/manual/index.html) for more information.

Comment: hm. I guess I don't need the embedded broker since I use an external one. What about the JMS-Plugin. Which benefits do I have from using it?

Comment: @Ralf Please see the updates to my answer for your additional questions.

Comment: Do you know how can i configure the embedded ActiveMQ broker?